# RailsTutorial Ch 9: signin_path is undefined local variable? Email already taken?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm going through RailsTutorial and I'm stuck at chapter 9.3. Rspec keeps giving me these errors when I try to run a suite test at the end of 9.3:

```
/Users/shaan/Sites/sample_app/spec/support/utilities.rb:15:in `sign_in': undefined local variable or method `signin_path' for #<Class:0x107759358> (NameError)

/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/validations.rb:56:in `save!': Validation failed: Email has already been taken (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
```

First I got the top error, then ran the test again many times and I keep getting the second error.

Below are my controller routes and test files:

- controller: http://pastebin.com/vJdCxthQ
- test: http://pastebin.com/SEVLd9Gg
- routes: http://pastebin.com/7LjA5Any

Utilities.rb:

```
include ApplicationHelper

def full_title(page_title)
  base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  if page_title.empty?
    base_title
  else
    "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
  end
end


def sign_in(user)
  visit signin_path
  fill_in "Email",    :with => user.email
  fill_in "Password", :with => user.password
  click_button "Sign in"
  # Sign in when not using Capybara as well.
  cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
end
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/7LjA5Any thanks for your helP!!!

Comment: Does the code work even though the tests fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this line

```
def sign_in(user)
visit signin_path
...
end
```

`signin_path` seems to be incorrect.  run `rake routes` to get the correct path & replace that with `signin_path`

Answer (score 0):

I spent a long time chasing this confusing error around too. In my case, the issue was a difference between Rails versions. Try renaming your 'spec/requests' directory to 'features'