# Ruby on Rails - undefined local variable or method `signin_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm getting this error but it doesn't make sense to me

heres the test:

```
describe "edit" do
        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

        before(:each) do
            sign_in user
            visit edit_user_path(user)
        end
        it{ should have_content('Profile Settings')}
        it{ should have_title(full_title('Settings'))}

        describe "invalid information" do
            before { click_button "Save changes" }
            it { should have_content('error') }
        end

        describe "valid information" do
            let(:new_name) { "Test name" }
            let(:new_email) { "test@email.com" }
            before do
                fill_in "Name", with: new_name
                fill_in "Email", with: new_email
                fill_in "Password", with: user.password
                fill_in "Password Confirmation", with: user.password

                click_button "Save changes"
            end
            it { should_not have_content('error')}
            it { should have_title(new_name)}
        end
    end
```

my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  resources :users do
    member do
        get :following, :followers
    end
  end
    resources :podcasts,            only: [:index, :new, :create, :destroy]
    resources :sessions,            only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
    resources :relationships,       only: [:create, :destroy]
    root to: 'static_pages#home'
    match '/about',  to: 'static_pages#about', via: 'get'
    match '/contact',  to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'
    match '/community',  to: 'users#community',   via: 'get'
    match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get'
    match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new',         via: 'get'
    match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy',     via: 'delete' 
end
```

when I run rake routes:

```
                signup GET        /signup(.:format)                         users#new
                signin GET        /signin(.:format)                         sessions#new
```

my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.1'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.8'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'
#gem "minitest", "~> 4.0"
gem 'devise'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin/activeadmin', branch: :master
gem 'rmagick', '2.13.2', :git=>'http://github.com/rmagick/rmagick.git'
gem 'carrierwave'
group :development, :test do
  #gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  # The following optional lines are part of the advanced setup.
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'spork-rails', '4.0.0'
  gem 'guard-spork', '2.1.0'
  gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'
  end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.2.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.0'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.3.0', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', github: 'bmabey/database_cleaner'

  # Uncomment this line on OS X.
  #gem 'growl', '1.0.3'

  # Uncomment these lines on Linux.
   gem 'libnotify', '0.8.0'

  # Uncomment these lines on Windows.
  # gem 'rb-notifu', '0.0.4'
  # gem 'win32console', '1.3.2'
  # gem 'wdm', '0.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

I did found two similar questions but didn't help much (or I'm understanding them wrong)

similar questions: [Rails Tutorial Chapter 8 - undefined local variable or method `signin_path'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443105/rails-tutorial-chapter-8-undefined-local-variable-or-method-signin-path)

[RailsTutorial Ch 9: signin_path is undefined local variable? Email already taken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276354/railstutorial-ch-9-signin-path-is-undefined-local-variable-email-already-taken)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you have `Sessions` controller, but you've mounted Devise, so please mind that native devise in my routes produce the following rows (look at the ending)

```
new_user_session GET        /users/sign_in(.:format)    devise/sessions#new
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)   devise/sessions#destroy
```

So I assume you must reference not `session#new`, but `device/sessions#new`. Try the following in your routes.rb:

Replace the rows

```
match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new',         via: 'get'
match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy',     via: 'delete'
```

with

```
get '/signin',  to: 'device/sessions#new'
delete '/signout', to: 'device/sessions#destroy'
```

Comment: Hey @zmli  thanks for the help, I found the solution and it turns out that any path wasn't be reconized.

Answer (score 0):

Actually  the prolbem was  the any path I put inside my specs files wans't been reconized

this questions helped me to solve the problem:

[Rspec and named routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475857/rspec-and-named-routes)

This answer was the solution:

Named routes should work if you put the following in rspec_helper.rb:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  ...
end
```

Is that how you set it up?

---

What is a little bit confusing is that I was following the  [sample_app_rails tutorial](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4) and this line wasn't there...

anyway thanks for the help everyone.